# Creating a signed S3 URL with Javascript

Tags: javascript, encryption, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am attempting to create a signed S3 URL using Javascript & NodeJS. I have used  [this](http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html)
specification.

```
var crypto     = require('crypto'),
    date       = 1331290899,
    resource   = '/myfile.txt',
    awskey     = "XXXX",
    awssecret  = "XXXX";

var stringToSign ='GET\n\n\n' + date + '\n\n' + resource;

var sig = encodeURIComponent(crypto.createHmac('sha1', awssecret).update(stringToSign ).digest('base64'));

var url = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket" +
       resource + "?AWSAccessKeyId=" + awskey + "&Expires="+ date +  
      "&Signature="+ sig
```

This creates a url similar to this:

```
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/test.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXX&Expires=1331290899&Signature=EciGxdQ1uOqgFDCRon4vPqTiCLc%3D
```

However, I receive the following error when accessing it:

```
SignatureDoesNotMatch

The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. 
Check your key and signing method.
```

What am I doing wrong when creating the signature?

**EDIT - ATTEMPT WITH KNOX**

I am now attempting to use Knox to produce a signed URL. I need to add headers with the request to force download. I have edited the following:

Added `amazonHeaders: 'response-content-disposition:attachment',` to client.signedUrl- http://jsfiddle.net/BpGNM/1/

Added `options.amazonHeaders + '\n' +` to `auth.queryStringToSign` - http://jsfiddle.net/6b8Tm/

The message that is now being sent to `auth.hmacSha1` to create the the sig is:

```
'GET\n\n\n1321374212\nresponse-content-disposition:attachment\n/meshmesh-dev/test/Readme.md'
```

I have then tried to access my new URL with the `response-content-disposition=attachment` added as GET var. However, I am still receiving the same error stated above.

Comment: Having the same issue as you, was this ever solved?

Answer (score 9):

I would try using Knox along with Node.Js . Its known to be a great combination and also itself utilizes the Node.JS Crypto library which is kind of what you're trying to do - saving you time:)

More info here : https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox

Than, you could just do something like:

```js
var knox = require('knox');
var s3Client = knox.createClient({
    key: 'XXX',
    secret: 'XXX',
    bucket: 'XXX'
});

var expires = new Date();
expires.setMinutes(expires.getMinutes() + 30);
var url =  s3Client.signedUrl(filename, expires);
```

**Edit:**
You could also look into Knox and just check what the signedUrl function does and implement that yourself.Than you could add to the `auth.signQuery` call an extra option called `amazonHeaders`:

```js
Client.prototype.signedUrl = function(filename, expiration){
  var epoch = Math.floor(expiration.getTime()/1000);
  var signature = auth.signQuery({
    amazonHeaders: 'response-content-disposition:attachment',
    secret: this.secret,
    date: epoch,
    resource: '/' + this.bucket + url.parse(filename).pathname
  });

  return this.url(filename) +
    '?Expires=' + epoch +
    '&AWSAccessKeyId=' + this.key +
    '&Signature=' + encodeURIComponent(signature);
};
```

Shai.

Comment: Thanks. I was using Knox, but I needed to send headers with the request (`response-content-disposition':attachment`) - so I tried to sign my own URLs. Any ideas how this is done with Knox?

Comment: I have updated my question above with the suggested edits to Knox. However, I have the same result.

Comment: I have to admit i'm kinda clueless from this point on :) Sorry i can't be of more assistance.

Comment: Did it work. I tried updating the knox client.js with amazonHeaders "response-content-disposition:attachment; filename=#{file._id}". But the response headers doesn't seem to have the content-disposition set

Comment: Current knox (since Mar 2013) supports a qs on the signedUrl options where you can put the response-content-disposition, no need to update the code. Use it like: `var headers = { 'response-content-disposition': 'attachment;filename=test.pdf'};`, `var url = client.signedUrl('/test.pdf', expires, { qs: headers });`

Comment: where did auth come from?

Answer (score 3):

maybe one too many newlines?

```
var stringToSign ='GET\n\n\n' + date + '\n\n' + resource;
```

If its any help here is a rubbish PHP implementation which definitely works:

```
class myS3Helper{
public function getSignedImageLink($timeout = 1800)
    {

        $now = new Zend_Date(); //Gives us a time object that is set to NOW
        $now->setTimezone('UTC'); //Set to UTC a-la AWS requirements
        $now->addSecond($timeout);
        $expirationTime = $now->getTimestamp(); //returns unix timestamp representation of the time.

        $signature = urlencode(
                base64_encode(
                        hash_hmac(
                                'sha1', $this->_generateStringToSign($expirationTime),
                                $my_aws_secretkey, 
                                true
                                )
                        )
                );

        //FIXME make this less ugly when I know it works
        $url = 'https://';
        $url .= Zend_Service_Amazon_S3::S3_ENDPOINT; //e.g s3.amazonaws.com
        $url .= $this->_getImagePath(); //e.g /mybucket/myFirstCar.jpg
        $url .='?AWSAccessKeyId=' . $my_aws_key;
        $url .='&Signature=' . $signature; //signature as returned by below function
        $url .='&Expires=' . $expirationTime;

        return $url;


    }

    protected function _generateStringToSign($expires)
    {   

        $string = "GET\n"; //Methods
        $string .= "\n";
        $string .= "\n";
        $string .= "$expires\n"; //Expires
        $string .= $this->_getImagePath();

        return $string;
    }
```

}

EDIT--

Have a look at this node.js s3 upload code, (it's not mine but found it lying around on my mac - so if anyone can attribute it to someone let me know and i'll do the props). Hopefully this might help (3rd time lucky)

https://gist.github.com/1370593

Comment: thanks. I will try and figure out what the function above is doing right. However, even without the extra `\n` after the expiry date - the sig still fails.

Comment: Sorry its a bit obtuse and not in the right language for you but it's the first thing i had to hand - if you have any questions let me know.

Comment: One last shot... Should the bucket be in the resource .e.g /mybucket/test.txt not just /text.txt?

Comment: Unfortunately the same result.

Answer (score 0):

My implementation using AWS-SDK and Rx.

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk"
import Rx from 'rx'

/*
* Credentials could be loaded from env variables
* http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-environment.html
* */

const s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});

export function getS3SignedImage(objectKey) {
    return Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
        s3.getSignedUrl('getObject',{
            Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
            Key: objectKey
        }, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                return observer.onError(err);
            }
            observer.onNext(data);
            observer.onCompleted();
        });
    });
}
```