# S3 signature mismatch for presigned URL

Tags: perl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to create a pre signed URL for Amazon S3.

The below code generates the same signature as the signature in the example in the S3 docs.
(https://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html)

However, when I plug in my own credentials etc, I get an error from AWS:
"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."

Given the code below seems to work, I presume my signing method is ok. Also, the credentials used are the ones
used to upload the file, so they are good too. They are root credentials, not an IAM user.

I have tried:

1) A file name with and without a period. 
2) A file in US standard as well as Ireland.
3) HTTP and HTTPS
4) SHA256 (although this breaks the example in the docs.)
5) Different web clients: wget, curl and Firefox.

I seem to be doing exactly the same as the php given here:
[Creating a signed S3 URL with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134799/creating-a-signed-s3-url-with-javascript)

This is the URL generated for the US standard. Bucket is "buck1bar", file is "foo.txt"

https://s3.amazonaws.com/buck1bar/foo.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJG5VR56AB5USIG5Q&Expires=1467893299&Signature=emdimX%2FWKYrcdhtPtE7eQ9ErWv30HNlAHaa9vlDODCY%3D

So, what am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

use MIME::Base64;

use Digest::HMAC;
use Digest::SHA;
use URI::Escape;


my $hmac3 = Digest::HMAC->new( 'OtxrzxIsfpFjA7SwPzILwy8Bw21TLhquhboDYROV', 'Digest::SHA');

$hmac3->add("GET\n\n\n1141889120\n/quotes/nelson");

my $signature = uri_escape( encode_base64 $hmac3->digest, '');

print  "vjbyPxybdZaNmGa%2ByT272YEAiv4%3D\n$signature\n";

# vjbyPxybdZaNmGa%2ByT272YEAiv4%3D
# vjbyPxybdZaNmGa%2ByT272YEAiv4%3D
```

Comment: Now, log into AWS immediately and invalidate the credentials that you have posted in this question.  Don't post your credentials in a public place.  You have potentially exposed yourself to significant liability if someone uses your credentials fraudulently.

Comment: The second line of the question: "The below code generates the same signature as the signature in the example in the S3 docs."

Comment: Hahaha my bad.  Now, here's where my head exploded on your behalf: *"Given the code below seems to work, I presume my signing method is ok. Also, the credentials used are the ones used to upload the file, so they are good too. They are root credentials, not an IAM user."*  Sweet: the code, below, includes your root credentials.

Comment: lol and I was so busy with that thought, I didn't even realize this was a Perl question.  Every module for S3 that I have looked at seems to have been written by somebody who really failed to grasp all of the necessary principles or properly handle exceptions or support all of the edge cases that were needed.   I threw up my hands and wrote my own, and never looked back except when code I had written using other people's modules was subsequently broken or needed enhancements.

Comment: Heh, no problem. I'm still unsure as to why it didn't work. Though now, if I really need to know I can poke around in the module. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further hackery, it turns out that the module I was using already does it.

```
my $client = Net::Amazon::S3::Client->new( s3 => $s3 );

my $bucket = $client->bucket( name => $bucket_name );

my $o = $bucket->object( key => 'key1', expires => '2016-07-08' );
my $uri = $o->query_string_authentication_uri();

print "$uri\n";
```